# How to delete element in binary file?

Tags: c, file, binary, structure, element

I thought that I should read all file into program, then remove file and open again with the same name, after that I should use for example function for and `if(!strcmp(.,.))` I should `fwrite` every each element from structure. I have tried in each way, but it didn't work. Could somebody help me with that? I would be very grateful.

```
void usun_element()
{
    int i;
    char nazwa[100];
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("katalog.bin", "rb" ))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Brak pliku katalog na dysku.\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    printf("Wpisz nazwe, ltora chcesz usunac z listy: ");
    scanf("%s", &nazwa);
        otworz();
        remove("katalog.bin");
        otworz();
        i=0;
        while(i<ost)
        {

        if(!strcmp(nazwa,kat[i].nazwa))
            {
                fwrite(&kat[i].nazwa, sizeof(kat), 1, fp);
                fwrite(&kat[i].typ, sizeof(kat), 1, fp);
                fwrite(&kat[i].rodzaj, sizeof(kat), 1, fp);
                fwrite(&kat[i].posiadane, sizeof(kat), 1, fp);
            }
    else
    {
        ost=i-1;
    }
    i++;


}
}
```

Comment: Don't be shy, show us your code. There is no other way to understand what exactly you want

Comment: Yes..Dabo is right :)

Comment: I used some words that aren't in english and i thought it would be some kind of trouble for u to understand ;)

Comment: `fwrite(&kat[i], sizeof(*kat), 1, fp);` if  fixed-length string.

Answer (score 1):

Match the format specifier to the argument.
Use the correct sizeof().
Suspicious about `ost=i-1;`.  Maybe not needed.

```
static const char *EnterNameToDelete = "Wpisz nazwe, ltora chcesz usunac z listy: ";
fputs(EnterNameToDelete, stdout);
// scanf("%s", &nazwa);
scanf("%99s", nazwa); // drop the &

if(!strcmp(nazwa, kat[i].nazwa)) {
  // use the correct sizeof()
  if (fwrite(&kat[i].nazwa    , sizeof(kat[i].nazwa)    , 1, fp) == 0 ||
      fwrite(&kat[i].typ      , sizeof(kat[i].typ)      , 1, fp) == 0 ||     
      fwrite(&kat[i].rodzaj   , sizeof(kat[i].rodzaj)   , 1, fp) == 0 ||
      fwrite(&kat[i].posiadane, sizeof(kat[i].posiadane), 1, fp)) {
    Handle_IO_Error();
  }
}
```

It would help if OP posted `kat` declaration and structure.